# Getting total coverage considering staggered values in awk

Tags: awk

Here is my data structure.

```
# id1    id2    len   start    end
# 9     16792   5475   4181     4232
# 11    16792   2317   1086     1137
# 11    32879   2317      8       60
# 11    32858   2317     10       52
# 11    30670   2317     17       63
# 14    12645    532      3       67
# 14    12645    532    158      222
# 14    11879    532      3      223
# 18    23847    644     64      285
# 18    30160    644     98      285
# 18    30160    644    345      477
# 18    30160    644    516      644
```

I want to get the coverage of id1 based on its length (column len) considering all entries start and end values.
The problem is that the multiple entries can have juxtapose values so considering the values in all entries would overrate the coverage. Also considering the smallest start value and biggest end value doesn't account for all since it can have gaps where not all length is represented.
Also, for each entrie that is included I need to add 1 so I can account for the whole coverage.

My expected result should be something like this

```
9 = 51 / 5475  = 0.009
11 = 108 / 2317 = 0.047
14 = 221 / 532  = 0.415
18 = 484 / 644  = 0.75
```

Comment: I do understand for `id 9` you get end - start `4232 - 4181 = 51`, but how do you get `108` for `id 11`?   Difference from Start to End for `Id 11` is `51 52 42 46`

Comment: @flebman: For ID 11 I get 103, for ID 14 I get 220, for ID 18 I get 481.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to add 1 for each piece that you are getting. But if you already got it without it, that is the easy part.